# iOS 7 arrayWithContentsOfFile with plist returning resulting in type invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, ios7

I have this code

```
@implementation LevelManager {
    NSArray * levelPacks;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Levels" ofType:@"plist"];
        levelPacks = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
    }
}
```

which reads the following plist file called `Levels.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>PackName</key>
        <string>First Pack</string>
        <key>Levels</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Name</key>
                <string>1</string>
                <key>Time</key>
                <integer>60</integer>
                <key>ScoreBronze</key>
                <integer>20</integer>
                <key>ScoreSilver</key>
                <integer>25</integer>
                <key>ScoreGold</key>
                <integer>30</integer>
                <key>Fish</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>OrangeFish</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Rarity</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>MinTime</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                    </dict>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Name</key>
                <string>2</string>
                <key>Time</key>
                <integer>60</integer>
                <key>ScoreBronze</key>
                <integer>25</integer>
                <key>ScoreSilver</key>
                <integer>30</integer>
                <key>ScoreGold</key>
                <integer>35</integer>
                <key>Fish</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>OrangeFish</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Rarity</key>
                        <integer>4</integer>
                        <key>MinTime</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                    </dict>
                    <key>PurpleFish</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Rarity</key>
                        <integer>2</integer>
                        <key>MinTime</key>
                        <integer>10</integer>
                    </dict>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>PackName</key>
        <string>Second Pack</string>
        <key>Levels</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Name</key>
                <string>1</string>
                <key>Time</key>
                <integer>60</integer>
                <key>ScoreBronze</key>
                <integer>20</integer>
                <key>ScoreSilver</key>
                <integer>25</integer>
                <key>ScoreGold</key>
                <integer>30</integer>
                <key>Fish</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>OrangeFish</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Rarity</key>
                        <integer>5</integer>
                        <key>MinTime</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                    </dict>
                    <key>PurpleFish</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Rarity</key>
                        <integer>3</integer>
                        <key>MinTime</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                    </dict>
                    <key>YellowFish</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Rarity</key>
                        <integer>1</integer>
                        <key>MinTime</key>
                        <integer>0</integer>
                    </dict>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

This worked until updating my code to iOS 7 where now I get an array with two items which both have the type of `invalid`.

When inspecting the variable in xcode it shows the error

```
(<invalid>) [0] = <error: expected ']'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
>
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Did you ever find the problem? Did you reboot your computer? If you want I'll send you the project with the file that works for me. This is starting to smell like some kind of corruption. Using Disk Utility, run verify disk on your computer to insure no corruption (and while at it fix permissions).

Comment: Still no luck. I'll run verify disk as that's a good idea. I was thinking I may have to start again and copy the contents of the files across bit by bit to see where it stops working. Thankfully the project only consists of 20-30 files so shouldn't take too long. But yeah it definitely seems like some odd kind of corruption. I may also blow away the whole project and do a fresh clone from the remote git repo at the last commit before I went to iOS 7 and see what happens there. I won't get a chance to try anything until tomorrow though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the plist as shown, put it into a file on a new project using Xcode 5, and ran it in the iOS7 simulator. It worked fine - I can see the two dictionaries in an array.

Suggestions:

- the file has gotten corrupt with non-printable characters, but when you pasted it into SO, they went away
- the file type is UTF-16 or something other than UTF-8. Look in Xcode, right Inspector pane (or us Terminal to query).

You may be able to solve it by deleting the original file, then creating a new one and pasting the text from your post in it as I did. Note that Xcode complains big time about an empty plist file, so you may want to do this in Terminal etc then add the file to Xcode.

Comment: I agree the file is okay

Comment: No joy I'm afraid. I copied and pasted into a new file and included it in the project and changed the filename in the code and I still get the same message. I've also tried creating the file from scratch using xcode and I still get the same.

Comment: I have managed to solve it. I just binned the whole project and did a clone from source control from the commit before I iOS 7. Then reapplied the changes I made to make it work on iOS 7. Still not sure what caused it but all working now.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a very old Xcode bug. Do an NSLog dump to see if the values are there. This inspector doesn't function even as late as Xcode 6.1! I'll make a radar.

Comment: I don't have the project any more to test it (I did raise this about a year ago). But thanks for raising the radar.

Comment: I posted it for the benefit of anyone who might have this issue. This is still a current bug in xcode. I landed here trying to solve it, for instance. I could have saved time if I had seen this post.

Comment: Yes that's excellent and I really appreciate it. My answer was in response to you telling me to `Do an NSLog dump to see if the values are there` which I can't do as I don't have the project any more.:)

Comment: No worries. Thanx for clarifying. I have a radar on this and Apple is investigating. They must not be aware of the issue.

Comment: BTW here's a little dummy project using your code that shows on a dump everything is there despite xcode's popover saying there's a problem. http://bit.ly/1veYuMS